# How does Collective Intelligence beat Experts' view?

Tags: collective-intelligence

I am interested in doing some Collective Intelligence programming, but wonder how it can work?

It is said to be able to give accurate predictions: the O'Reilly Programming Collective Intelligence book, for example, says a collection of traders' action actually can predict future prices (such as corn) better than an expert can.

Now we also know in statistics class that, if it is a room of 40 students taking exam, there will be 3 to 5 students who will get an "A" grade.  There might be 8 that get "B", and 17 that got "C", and so on.  That is, basically, a bell curve.

So from these two standpoints, how can a collection of "B" and "C" answers give a better prediction than the answer that got an "A"?

Note that the corn price, for example, is the accurate price factoring in weather, demand of food companies using corn, etc, rather than "self fulfilling prophecy" (more people buy the corn futures and price goes up and more people buy the futures again).  It is actually predicting the supply and demand accurately to give out an accurate price in the future.

How is it possible?

**Update:** can we say Collective Intelligence won't work in stock market euphoria and panic?

Comment: Not programming related?

Comment: This is an interesting question but is not programming related.

Comment: It's about a specific class of algorithms and how (well) they work.  Seems programming-related to me.

Comment: On SO, you may be better off researching Collective Stupidity :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Wisdom of Crowds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wisdom_of_Crowds) wiki page offers a good explanation.

In short, you don't always get good answers. There needs to be a few conditions for it to occur.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you might want to think of the following "model" for a guess:

```
guess = right answer + error
```

If we ask a lot of people a question, we'll get lots of different guesses. But if, for some reason, the distribution of `error`s is symmetric around zero (actually it just has to have zero mean) then the average of the guesses will be a pretty good predictor of the right answer.

Note that the guesses don't necessarily have to be good -- i.e., the errors could indeed be large (grade B or C, rather than A) as long as there are grade B and C answers distributed on both sides of the right answer.

Of course, there are cases where this is a terrible model for our guesses, so collective intelligence won't *always* work...

Answer (score 1):

Crowd Wisdom techniques, like prediction markets, work well in some situations, and poorly in others, just as other approaches (experts, for instance) have their strengths and weaknesses.  The optimal arenas therefore, are ones where no other approaches do very well, and prediction markets can do well.  Some examples include predicting public elections, estimating project completion dates, and predicting the prevalence of epidemics.  These are areas where information is spread around sparsely, and experts haven't found effective models that reliably predict.

The general idea is that market participants make up for one another's weaknesses.  The expectation isn't that the markets will always predict every outcome correctly, but that, due to people noticing other people's mistakes, they won't miss crucial information as often, and that over the long haul, they'll do better.  In cases where the exerts actually know the answer, they'll be able to influence the outcome.  Different experts can weigh in on different questions, so each has more influence where they have the most knowledge.  And as markets continue over time, each participant gets feedback from their gains and losses that makes them better informed about which kinds of questions they actually understand and which ones they should stay away from.

In a classroom, people are often graded on a curve, so the distribution of grades doesn't tell you much about how good the answers were.  Prediction markets calibrate all the answers against actual outcomes.  This public record of successes and failures does a lot to reinforce the mechanism, and is missing in most other approaches to forecasting.

Answer (score 0):

Collective intelligence is really good at coming up to to problems that have complex behavior behind them, because they are able to take multiple sources of opinions/attributes to determine the end result. With a setup like this, training helps to optimize the end result of the processes.

Answer (score -1):

The fault is in your analogy, both opinions are not equal. Traders predict direct profit for their transaction (the little part of the market they have overview over), while the expert tries to predict the overall field.

IOW the overall traders position is pieced together like a jigsaw puzzle based on a large amount of small opinions for their respective piece of the pie (where they are assumed to be experts).

A single mind can't process that kind of detail, which is why the overall position MIGHT overshadow the real expert. Note that this is particularly phenomon is usually restricted to a fairly static market, not in periods of turmoil. Expert usually do better then, since they are often better trained and motivated to avoid going with general sentiment. (which is often comparable to that of a lemming in times of turmoil)

The problem with the class analogy is that the grading system doesn't assume that the students are masters in their (difficult to predict) terrain, so it is not comparable.

P.s.  note that the base axiom depends on all players being experts in a small piece of the field. One can debate if this requirement actually transports well to a web 2 environment.